# Using future callback inside akka actor

Tags: scala, concurrency, callback, akka, future

I've found in Akka docs:

> When using future callbacks, such as onComplete, onSuccess, and onFailure, inside actors you need to carefully avoid closing over the containing actor’s reference, i.e. do not call methods or access mutable state on the enclosing actor from within the callback.

So does it mean that i should always use `future pipeTo self` and then call some functions? Or i can still use callbacks with method, then how should i avoid concurrency bugs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means this:

```
class NotThreadSafeActor extends Actor {

  import context.dispatcher

  var counter = 0

  def receive = {
    case any =>
      counter = counter + 1
      Future {
        // do something else on a future
        Thread.sleep(2000)
      }.onComplete {
        _ => counter = counter + 1
      }
  }
}
```

In this example, both the actor's receive method, and the Future's onComplete change the mutable variable `counter`. In this toy example its easier to see, but the Future call might be nested methods that equally capture a mutable variable.

The issue is that the `onComplete` call might execute on a different thread to the actor itself, so its perfectly possible to have one thread executing `receive` and another executing `onComplete` thus giving you a race condition. Which negates the point of an actor in the first place.

Comment: I'm not that interested in accessing/mutating variables as calling methods from the callback. In which cases it's not safe to call a method from the callback (if it doesn't mutate anything, just does some logic)?

Comment: Is another `Actor` mutating its inner state?

Comment: It's perfectly safe for a callback to call methods that don't have side effects (mutate state). If you want to mutate state then have your onComplete / onSuccess etc send a message to the actor so its queued properly. @goral not sure what you are asking

Comment: If for example some other `Actor` would change its inner state, then if we are running it on different threads then this logic may be incorrect (if it depends on this state). But if `Actor`s task is pure in term of functions it performs I would also say that it's safe.

Comment: in the example above, should we use `Await.result` and a pinned dispatcher if we would like to ensure that the counter is updated before the next message is handled by `receive`? assume before `Future {}` block we retrieve the counter's state. If we use a priority mailbox with `result pipeTo self` pattern, it seems that the counter will only be eventually consistent?

Comment: @monkjack Can you provide example how this should be handled properly?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should send a message to the enclosing actor if the callback mutates internal state of the actor. This is the easiest (and preferred) way to avoid races.

Comment: But if doesn't mutate any state, just calls some methods, which might also return a future with a callback (nested callbacks)?

Answer (score 0):

I think I would be remiss if I did not mention here that I've made a small utility for circumventing this limitation. In other words, my answer to your question is No, you shouldn't use such an inconvenient workaround, you should use https://github.com/makoConstruct/RequestResponseActor

> **how does it work?**
>
> Basically, behind the futures and the promises, it transmits every query in a `Request(id:Int, content:Any)`, and when it receives `Response(id, result)` it completes the future that corresponds to id with the value of `result`. It's also capable of transmitting failures, and as far as I can tell, akka can only register query timeouts. The RequestResponseActor supplies a special implicit execution context to apply to callbacks attached to the futures waiting for a Response message. This blunt execution context ensures they're executed while the Response message is being processed, thus ensuring the Actor has exclusive access to its state when the future's callbacks fire.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help. It is an experiment I did and the test is quite conclusive... however, it is still an experiment, so do not take that as an expertise.

https://github.com/Adeynack/ScalaLearning/tree/master/ActorThreadingTest/src/main/scala/david/ActorThreadingTest

Open to comments or suggestions, of course.

Futures with actors is a subject I am very interested in.