# Exploring Akka Typed Actors Functional Vs Object Oriented Way

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-typed

I had worked on Akka actors (non typed), recently started to write Akka typed actors, and found two ways of achieving one were the functional way and another was the object-oriented way (similar to old).

I was interested in understanding the encapsulation of state in both functional and object-oriented way. So wrote a method for the functional way and a class for the object-oriented way.

**Functional Way:**

```scala
def webSocketConnections(l: List[ActorRef[Message]] = List.empty): Behavior[WebSocketMsg] = {
    Behaviors.receive[WebSocketMsg] {
      (context, message) => {
        message match {
          case Model.UserAdded(actorRef) => webSocketConnections(actorRef :: l)
          case Model.BroadcastToAll(msg) =>
            context.spawnAnonymous(broadCastActorBehaviour) ! Broadcast(l, msg)
            Behaviors.same
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Object-Oriented Way**

```scala
class WebSocketConnectionMaintainer(actorContext: ActorContext[WebSocketMsg]) extends
  AbstractBehavior[WebSocketMsg](actorContext) {
  private var actorRefL: List[ActorRef[Message]] = List.empty

  override def onMessage(msg: WebSocketMsg): Behavior[WebSocketMsg] = {
    msg match {
      case Model.UserAdded(actorRef) =>
        actorRefL =  actorRef :: actorRefL
        Behaviors.same
      case Model.BroadcastToAll(msg) =>
        actorContext.spawnAnonymous(broadCastActorBehaviour) ! Broadcast(actorRefL, msg)
        Behaviors.same
    }
  }
}
```

If you observe both the cases, in the case of functional way the state gets encapsulated as a param, not sure whether it can have issues with respect to stack safety, as it can crash due to stack overflow error after a lot of calls right?

But if you observe the object-oriented way, it's just mutating the list directly which won't cause any stack overflow issue.

And another problem that I was finding is, I can only use `context.spawn` for spawning a functional way actor, but in the case of object-oriented, I need a context of a particular type.
What to do if I want to create both functional and object-oriented actors together?

Comment: In general, having mutable state inside an actor is fine because actors are thread safe. But if you have a future callback for mutable state inside actors you might break the actor encapsulation, like is showing here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23908461/2096986). So this is why it is preferable to have stateless actors by implementing the functional way

Comment: @Felipe, Correct, I know its thread-safe, but I'm talking about stack safety and spawning a actor

Comment: What do you mean by `stack overflow`? Are you saying that in case you try to spawn a lot of child actors, at some point something will crash?

Comment: No @Felipe, in case of functional way of actor, won't the behaviour be getting called itself and it will get stack overflow right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the stack safety concern, the short answer is that the apparent recursion is trampolined, so it won't blow the stack.  See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64972768/how-to-make-recursive-calls-within-behaviors-receive/64977466).

For spawning an OO-defined typed actor, you use `Behaviors.setup` which injects the context:

```
def ooBehavior: Behavior[WebSocketMsg] = Behaviors.setup { ctx =>
  new WebSocketConnectionMaintainer(ctx)
}
context.spawn(ooBehavior)
```